# Session or Cookies in login page = master page = child page

Tags: session, cookies, resources, multilingual, app-globalresources

I' creating a multilanguage website and I have some files :

1. login page.
2. master page.
3. child page using master page.

In `login` page, I used link control for choose language by user :

```
<table class="borderlang" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px; width: auto; height: auto;">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Language :" meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="?lang=vi" runat="server" id="linkVietnameseLang">
                    <img src="Content/Images/VNlogo.jpg" style="height: 20px; width: auto; padding-left: 10px;" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="?lang=en" runat="server" id="linkEnglishLang">
                    <img src="Content/Images/USALogo.png" style="height: 20px; width: auto; padding-left: 10px;" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I use `BasePage.cs` with code :

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["lang"]))
        {
            Session["lang"] = Request["lang"];
        }
        string lang = Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]);
        string culture = string.Empty;
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("en") == 0)
        {
            culture = "en-US";
        }
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("vi") == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            culture = "vi-VN";
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
}
```

So in login page I use :

```
public partial class Login : BasePage
```

To use BasePage.

In this form have some items that I can't use local resource, so I used 2 resources : `global resource` and `local resource`. But I don't care because when I choose language in link -> language change and global and local resource are changed, too.

Now, when I login, website will redirect to a page using master page. In master page I put a dropdown for user in case they wanna change language again :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="True" meta:resourcekey="ddlLanguageResource1">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Tiếng ViệT" Value="vi-VN" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="EnglisH" Value="en-US" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

And in master page I add :

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        }
```

and :

```
protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
        cookie.Value = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        //Set the culture and reload the page for immediate effect. 
        //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                      new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                      new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
        Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
    }
```

In global.asax is :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];
        if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("vi-VN");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("vi-VN");
        }
    }
```

***Question 1*** : How can I use session or cookies of link value (in login page) to master page : ddlanguage value = session or cookies of lang ??

Now, in child page using master page. I must use local resource because if use global resource I must use `<%$ Resources:nameresource, keysource%> ->` too slow.
And I have a problem : in child page with local resoure, culture and uiculture value is not depending on ddlanguage value in master page.

***Question 2*** : How can I set culture and uiculture value in child page = ddlanguage value in master page.

And result is : `lang value in login page = ddlanguage` dropdown value in `master page = culture` and `uiculture in child page` using that masterpage. But can change ddlanguage value in masterpage and culture`and`uiculture in child page will change, too.

```
.
```

I'm an amateur in coding, so I hope have solution in my case.
Thank very very much (and sorry for my English).

Answer (score 0):

```
In program.cs
user name can set Globals variable
namespace GlobalVariables
{
    public static class Globals
    {
       static Globals() 
       {
         userName="";
       }
       public static void setusername(int[] newInt)
       {
         setusername = newInt;
    }
    public static string userName { get; private set; }
}

you can set or get every child or parent form
inherit namespace like in another child or parent form
using GlobalVariables;

to set Globals session or cookiee
Globals.setusername(userName.ToString()));

you can check and restrict page
username=Globals.userName;

 Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "rangarajakrishnan"
    Response.Cookies("userInfo")("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString
    Response.Cookies("userInfo").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)

    Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("userInfo")
    aCookie.Values("userName") = "mike"
    aCookie.Values("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString
    aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
```